# aspectj compile time weaving - ajc$perSingletonInstance is null

Tags: aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I aimed to implement compile-time weaving in my codebase and discovered the AspectJ Maven plugin (https://dev-aspectj.github.io/aspectj-maven-plugin/).

```
aspectj.version = 1.9.21
maven-compiler.version = 3.11.0
java.version = 21
```

I made the following modifications:

Added the following code under the `dependencies` section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Included the following code under the `<plugins>` section:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-compiler.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <d>${project.build.directory}/unwoven-classes</d>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>dev.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
        <sources/>
        <weaveDirectories>
            <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/unwoven-classes</weaveDirectory>
        </weaveDirectories>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Due to compatibility issues between Lombok and AspectJ, I initially compile to `unwoven-classes` before proceeding to `target/classes`. Running `mvn clean compile` results in a successful build with `[INFO] Join point...`. However, during application startup, I encounter the following error:

```
Caused by: org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException: Exception while initializing com.xyz.apirest.authorization.EnsureFromMonolith: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.xyz.apirest.authorization.EnsureFromMonolith: method 'void <init>()' not found     at com.xyz.apirest.authorization.EnsureFromMonolith.aspectOf(EnsureFromMonolith.java:1)     at com.xyz.apirest.v1.internal.workflows.InternalDisbursementController.<clinit>(InternalDisbursementController.java:1)     ... 124 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.xyz.apirest.authorization.EnsureFromMonolith: method 'void <init>()' not found     at com.xyz.apirest.authorization.EnsureFromMonolith.ajc$postClinit(EnsureFromMonolith.java:1)     at com.xyz.apirest.authorization.EnsureFromMonolith.<clinit>(EnsureFromMonolith.java:1)     ... 125 common frames omitted
```

The relevant code snippet is as follows:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EnsureFromMonolith {
    private final AuthenticationProfile authenticationProfile;
    private final XYZJwtAuthenticationConfig xyzJwtAuthenticationConfig;
    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EnsureFromMonolith.class);

    @Around(value = "(execution(public * *(..)) && within(@com.xyz.apirest.authorization.RequireFromMonolith *)) || @annotation(com.xyz.apirest.authorization.RequireFromMonolith)")
    public Object ensureFromMonolith(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        if (authenticationProfile.getAid() == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).build();
        } else if (!validateProfile(authenticationProfile, xyzJwtAuthenticationConfig.getMonolithAuthorizedClientId())) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }

        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }

    public static boolean validateProfile(AuthenticationProfile authenticationProfile, String monolithClientId) {
        return authenticationProfile.getAid().equals(monolithClientId);
    }
}
```

I've tried the solutions recommended in [AspectJ not working with compile time weaving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832530/aspectj-not-working-with-compile-time-weaving) and [How to build aspectj project using maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233526/how-to-build-aspectj-project-using-maven) without success.

My goal is to have the application startup successfully with AspectJ functioning as intended.`